# Cakephp 3.x create something like a data collection to fill table rows

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have created a custom form builder module with Cakephp 3 and saving all the form data inside a content table. Now I want to create a array that contains all content based on the form_id.

My Content table inside my database is like this:

```
ID | form_id | content 
-- | ------- | ------
1  | 1       | lorum  
2  | 1       | lorum  
3  | 2       | lorum  
4  | 2       | lorum
```

I want to create a array like:

```
Array(
   Array(form_id => 1,
      Array(content => lorum, content => lorum)
   )
   Array(form_id => 2,
      Array(content => lorum, content => lorum)
   )
)
```

Comment: I have only tried to get all the records, but I haven't a idea to create a query that can do what I want to do. I hope that you have some.

Comment: I don't see any code from you. Only some HTML you want and some table structure. Did you read the docs? Did you try the official Blog tutorial by CakePHP?

Comment: It may help if you'd describe the actual problem that you have with building the query. Do you actually know what it should look like at all? I don't really see how you'd need to do anything other than grouping _the results_ by `form_id` for easier iterating, and that doesn't even need to be done on query builder level.

Comment: I've updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That array looks invalid. Given your previous table example, I suppose you're looking for a structure similar to:

```
[
    1 => [
        ['content' => 'lorum'],
        ['content' => 'lorum']
    ],
    2 => [
        ['content' => 'lorum'],
        ['content' => 'lorum']
    ]
]
```

where `1` and `2` are the `form_id` values. That is what `Collection::groupBy()` can easily produce, the only difference would be that the nested sets would also contain the `form_id` key additionally to `content`.

```
$grouped = $query->groupBy('form_id');
```

See also **[Cookbook > Collections > Collection::groupBy()](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/collections.html#Cake%5CCollection%5CCollection::groupBy)**